# how to access cakephp model value in contoller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I want to mail verify key field value on mail when customer used forgot password option. My query is working perfect. when i debug in view i am able to see filed value but in controller i am not able to access that value.

Here is my controller query.

```
public function forgot() {
    if ($this->User->validates() ) {
    $auserlogin = $this->User->forgot($this->data['user']['email']);
    $this->set('auserlogin', $auserlogin);
    $message="Someone requested to reset password \n\n";
    $message=$message."Verify Key : ".$auserlogin['0']['user']['verifykey']."\n\n";
    $message=$message."Thanks\n\n";
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->from(array('mail@gmail.in' => 'mail'))
    ->to($this->data['user']['email'])
    ->subject('Forgot Password')
    ->send($message);
    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'password'));
    }
}
```

In view part i am able to see query is working via this

```
$auserlogin['0']['user']['verifykey'];
```

but i want to mail this verifykey to user so i used

```
$message="Verify Key : ".$auserlogin['0']['user']['verifykey']."\n\n";
```

OR

```
$this->set('verifykey', $auserlogin['0']['user']['verifykey']);
$message="Verify Key : ".$verifykey."\n\n";
```

both are not working in mail i am not receiving variable value on mail i received only

```
Verify Key :
```

Comment: Which cakephp version you are working on and please share the form part too

Comment: Can you share the controller function and the form part?

Comment: put `$this->log($message, 'debug');` before mail sending and check you log file.

Comment: @AmanRawat yes is logfile value is showing but on mail still value is blank

Comment: whats the output in `pr($auserlogin);`

Comment: @NewbeeDev Array([0] => Array([user] => Array([verifykey] => prFaUzAPrCAcIprIhjvWbvwqI)))

Comment: @ptailor that's the output in the controller or view?

Comment: @NewbeeDev in both same output

Comment: @ptailor how about the output of this `echo "Verify Key : ".$auserlogin['0']['user']['verifykey']."\n\n"`

Comment: @NewbeeDev controller Verify Key :   or inside view Verify Key : prFaUzAPrCAcIprIhjvWbvwqI

Comment: @ptailor I see...... try putting `$this->set('auserlogin', $auserlogin);` after you calling it

Comment: @NewbeeDev i already write this after call model function but same issue.

Comment: @ptailor your code seems correct to me. don't see how that variable returns empty

Comment: @NewbeeDev Undefined variable: auserlogin [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 55]  now this error happen

Comment: @ptailor let's continue here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129421/how-to-access-cakephp-model-value-in-contoller

Answer (score 0):

Model name should be in capitalised inside controller.  $auserlogin['0']['User']['verifykey']

Credit goes [newbee-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3481654/newbee-dev)

Comment: I see. it's because in local it's not case sensitive (the model name or index) but in live it is. correct me if I am wrong. I once encounter that also.